# Ошибка размерности массива в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, numpy, keras

Пишу нейронную сеть для распознавания цифр, вылезла ошибка - не могу разобраться как изменить размерность массива, код ниже

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

json_file = open("fully_mesh_network.json", "r")
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("fully_mesh_network.h5")

loaded_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

img_path = '2.png'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(28,28), grayscale=True)

x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = 255 - x
x/= 255
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)

prediction = loaded_model.predict(x)
prediction = np_utils.categorical_probas_to_classes(prediction)
print(prediction)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 28, 28, 1)
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, как именно Вы разобрались. Такая же проблема - замучался совсем:(((

Comment: Пробовали ? "x = x.reshape(1, 28**2)" ругается на " "AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.np_utils' has no attribute 'categorical_probas_to_classes'" " ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по ошибке ваша модель ожидает 2D массив на входе.

попробуйте так:

```
x = x.reshape(28, 28)
```

PS метод `np_utils.categorical_probas_to_classes()` - отсутствует в современных версиях `Keras`. Вместо него можно попробовать использовать метод: [`keras.utils.to_categorical()`](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical)

Comment: Вместо этой строчки ?  -   x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)

Comment: вместо или после...

Comment: Не выходит  Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 784) but got array with shape (28, 28)

Comment: попробуйте так: `x = x.reshape(1, 28**2)`

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка вылезла "AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.np_utils' has no attribute 'categorical_probas_to_classes'"

Comment: Не зная что ваша модель ожидает на входе - это игра в угадайку... ;)

Comment: Буду разбираться, и на этом спасибо :)

Comment: @NickSightless, попробуйте `np_utils.to_categorical()`. У вас не числовые данные на входе?

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!!! Сейчас найду как отблагодарить(а то первый раз на оверфлоу - еще не разобрался )

Comment: @NickSightless Если не разобрались как отблагодарить. то [ознакомтесь здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reputation).